# Setup Ubuntu L2TP VPN server and authenticate users with certificates

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, certificate, l2tp

I am trying to setup an L2TP server on my Ubuntu VPS and use certificates to authenticate users rather than a password.
The reason behind this choice is that I don't want to have plain text passwords written in the /etc/ppp/chap-secrets file and having an Active Directory service to keep track of all the users is not an option.

I have currently installed openswan and successfully set up the server to work with the shared secret + the user's password.

The next step is to switch from user passwords to certificates.

How can I do that?

How do I edit the configuration of L2TP and IPSec to allow that and how can I issue certificates to users?

Thank you very much,
Nick

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  From [this writeup](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/AndroidVPNServer) and others I've seen, the most common setup involves 3 (!!!) passwords, one each for IPSec, L2TP, and PPPD.  As that links shows, one of the 3 (IPSec) can be replaced with per-user certs, using `racoon`.  Ideally I'd like to get the number of passwords down to zero :-/

Comment: Hi, not really. I ended up setting up a "machine certificate" which all users share and is used to authenticate the IPsec tunnel. Then I use unix users' passwords to authenticate pppd.